# USA road trip - tolls in Iowa, Kansas, Missouri, Oklahoma and Texas

Tags: usa, tolls, texas, oklahoma, kansas

We're taking a long road trip from Saskatchewan to the Dallas-Fort Worth area later this year.  On prior long road trips I've gotten toll transponders (in Illinois and Florida), paid cash, or done drive-by-plate billing (Toronto, ON and the Seattle, WA area, although it turns out neither jurisdiction bills Saskatchewan drivers :) ).

Our route takes us through North Dakota, eastern South Dakota, and Iowa along the Nebraska border to the Kansas City area, then southwest through Wichita and Oklahoma City to Dallas-Fort Worth, then northwest to Santa Fe, north to Denver, then to the Black Hills of South Dakota before we go home.

I believe the only tolled roads we'll face are in Kansas, Oklahoma and Texas.  I've ordered a TxTag, which has no maintenance fees and will take care of us, it seems, in both Kansas and Texas.  Is this correct?

And what about Oklahoma?  Can I pay cash tolls?  Is exact change required?  (Or can one pay by card?)  It seems that a single transponder for this entire area isn't too practical.

Am I missing any areas?

For the record, the Illinois and Florida passes have no maintenance fees and mail to any US address (and I have one).  They saved us a lot of time driving in those states.  I'd like to have as much of that benefit on this trip as I can - fewer things to think about.

Comment: There are toll roads around the Denver area, though you can avoid them by taking alternate routes.  There are also tolled "express lanes" on some otherwise non-toll roads, but again you can avoid the toll by just using regular lanes.  These are electronic-only, by license plate or RFID tag.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the tip.  We likely can avoid them, but if not, it seems most jurisdictions are too cheap to pay for access to Saskatchewan motor license records :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I-44 in Oklahoma, at least, still has cash tolls on its tolled sections. However, I would recommend carrying sufficient coins to pay the tolls, because the cash booth to accept bills is not always manned, and while the mainline toll booths will still have lanes with mechanical bill acceptors, they’re finicky and the “coins only” lane will have a *much* shorter line.

Comment: Thanks.  It turns out we won't need to travel on I-44, so I think we can totally escape paying tolls in Oklahoma.